# Set default value for last two months from calendar hierachy ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

Here beow is my code i want to set default value for last two months

This code is working fine for current Month

[image: expression code]

Comment: This will depend on how your parameter is used, I think. From your expression, it seems that your query will only handle one value.

Comment: Yes its only handle one value . so i want to pass value october , november for query parameter

Comment: Well, to retrieve data for the last **two** months, it will have to be able to handle **two** values (IMHO).

Comment: yes but i dont know how to pass in parameter value(october,november) in expression dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You can add two default values, one will have an expression to the previous month and the other can have an expression for 2 months ago. All you have to do is replace all the occurrences of `now()` with something like this:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Month, -1, Now())
```

This will get you the parts of the date for last month.